# XPATH. Quiero seleccionar un nodo hijo de un ancestor que no lo es totalmente

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

Tengo una página web con elementos dinámicos. Agradecería mucho si alguien me ilumina y me dice como puedo seleccionar mediante `xpath` un nodo de un elemento “ancestor” diferenciador que no llega a ser totalmente “ancestor”. No sé cómo explicarlo.

Os presento el HTML para verlo mejor.

```
<div id="PRMT_N0x12209340x0x14878c8c_NS_" class="clsPromptComponent" style="text-align: left;">
<input type="hidden" name="p_ReqStatus" value="">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="10px">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="10" height="20" role="presentation">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top"><img id="PRMT_IMG_ERROR_N0x12209340x0x14878c8c_NS_" src="images/error_timed_small_off.gif" class="clsErrorRequired" valign="top" height="10" width="10" border="0" alt=""></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td width="">
                <div id="PRMT_SV_CONTAINER_N0x12209340x0x14878c8c_NS_" class="">
                    <select id="PRMT_SV_N0x12209340x0x14878c8c_NS_" class="clsSelectControl pv" role="listbox" multiple="" size="11" aria-multiselectable="true" aria-invalid="false" style="width: 200px;">
                        <option value="44" dv="Approved" role="option" aria-selected="true">Approved</option>
                        <option value="45" dv="Cancelled" role="option" aria-selected="false">Cancelled</option>
```

Quiero seleccionar la `<option dv="Approved">`, el problema es que con el xpath que yo especifico: `//select/option[@dv="Approved"]`, me dice que no es único ya que hay en la web varios SELECT con esa opción y lo único que los diferencia es el `<input>` que hay mas arriba. No sé cómo seleccionar ese nodo, teniendo en cuenta el input diferenciador de arriba.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Necesito encontrar "<option value="44" dv="Approved" role="option" aria-selected="true">Approved</option>" ese nodo, pero existen 4 identicos en la web y el único elemento que los diferencia es el <input> que hay más arriba, es decir "<input type="hidden" name="p_ReqStatus" value="">, porque el name de los otros input son distintos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes utlizar la siguiente query:

```
//input[@name="p_ReqStatus"]/following-sibling::table//select/option[@dv="Approved"]
```

Lo que se traduce a:

- A partir del `input` con el atributo `name="p_ReqStatus"` buscar en el hermano siguiente que sea una `table` el `option` con atributo `dv="Approved"`